# I got errors 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' when build APK for released

Tags: android, release, keystore, findbugs

I want to Generate Signed APK, and already have keystore, but when i want to build APK, i got error message like this one

i tried this one https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle/issues/154 but still got same problem.

```
Cannot find a version of 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' that satisfies the version constraints: 
   Dependency path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
   Constraint path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Constraint path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Constraint path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Constraint path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Constraint path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Constraint path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Constraint path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Constraint path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Dependency path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.guava:guava:24.1-jre' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
   Constraint path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Constraint path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Constraint path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Constraint path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Constraint path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Constraint path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Constraint path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Constraint path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Constraint path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Constraint path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Constraint path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Constraint path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Constraint path 'RushTrailDriver:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
```

previously, on my gradle i don't adding 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305'. It makes me confused. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You can obtain that `jsr305` library via Maven from: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below lines in your build.gradle file(Module: app) inside the android section.

```
       configurations.all {
          resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
        }
```

It worked for me!